# Export data from multiple DataTables

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables

I have a group of jQuery UI tabs and a DataTable inside each, with DOM elements named respectively (e.g. "tabs-1" will contain table "choice1").
I have tried activating `PDF` button in the tables and it works good.
Now, I need to fetch data from **all** tables in tabs and make a PDF out of that.
I guess iterating through all tables and stacking the return values of `table.rows.data()` in one collection will do. Correct me if I need something else to be passed to pdf creating methods. 
I have dug a bit deeper and discovered `table.buttons.exportData()` which seems to be even closer to what I'm looking for.

Second thing is the method itself. [This](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf) page didn't help me much, unfortunately. I'm not even sure that I don't have to mess with pdfmake library myself.
I am just hoping that if the "export this one current table" functionality is already implemented, it is somehow possible to use this implementation with desired set of datatable rows without reinventing this implementation.
Can you confirm my hopes and guesses?

P.S. All new tables are generated from a template, so column count and names are same between those tables

Comment: There is no method that does a merge of all tables and export PDF.. if I were you I would get all the tables data , merge them together and try to generate a PDF ( which might take time for the process) .. Else if the table size is small I would also have a hidden table which holds all the data and trigger this table export when any of the other table export button is clicked. This looks faster to the user

Comment: @Reddy I'm not looking for method that collects things for me. I'm looking for a method that will accept all the collected return values of `buttons.exportData()` and create a pdf as it does with single table when you press `PDF` button. Hidden table could be a great idea if it hasn't required me to add another field to just tell from which table this particular row has come and then *sorting rows out* when it comes to producing an output

Comment: Currently I am not aware of any such method. Also is all your table in the exact same format?

Comment: @Reddy yes, they are all in the same format